# Extracting values of elements in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I have a python data-structure as follows:

```
A = [{'abc': 'kjkjl'},{'abc': 'hjhjh'},{'abc': '78787'}]
```

How can I remove the 'abc' from A and make a new list:

```
B = ['kjkjl','hjhjh','78787']
```

EDIT: I still get the following error using the solutions:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u03b9' in position 10:             character maps to <undefined>
```

The actual data structure is as follows:

```
A =

{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic de la communaut des fans de Star Wars  '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet Topic Unique La Communaut des Fans de Pirates des Caraibes '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Pandora - Topic de la communaut des fans de Avatar et de James Cameron '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Au-del de Brokeback ple-mle'} {u'thread': u'Sujet X Men 4 The Wolvy Gang fanfic'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Transformers 3'} {u'thread': u'Sujet le Photogramme - saison 2'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Une mditation sur lamour de la beaut'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 2'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Inception'} {u'thread': u'ALED - Cin\u03b9ma'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Twilight - Chapitre 3 hsitation'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic unique La Justice league prvu pour 2013'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 1'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 1'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Avatar'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Rebecca and Billy s fan'} {u'thread': u'Sujet ALED - Bistrot'} {u'thread': u'Sujet ALED - Jeux'} {u'thread': u'ALED - Bistrot'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic Unique News Transformers III'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic Unique News Scream 4 Infos photos BA promo Sans HSFlood '} {u'thread': u'ALED - Jeux'} {u'thread': u'Sujet ALED - Musique'} {u'thread': u'ALED - Musique'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Batmanet une Lgende '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur The Dark Knight Rises'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Resident Evil Afterlife'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Jake Sully lhomme qui marchait dans sa tte '} {u'thread': u'Sujet De qui Peter Jackson croit-il se moquer'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Saw 3D'} {u'thread': u'[Topic Unique] News Spider-Man reboot'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Dbat autours sur les news ET rumeurs D'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Scream 4'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Le Top 100 des internautes'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic des news Bilbo le Hobbit prquelle du Seigneur des Anneaux Spoilers possibles'} {u'thread': u'D\u03b9bat autours sur les news ET rumeurs -D'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - The Dark Knight Rises'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Top Cinma 2010'} {u'thread': u'Topic des news Bilbo le Hobbit (pr\u03b9quelle du Seigneur des Anneaux) Spoilers possibles-'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Pirates des Carabes la Fontaine de Jouvence'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Lunique et vritable explication de matrix revolutions'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic DE SECOURS de la communaut des fans de STAR WARS'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur X-Men Le commencement'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - X-Men Le commencement'} {u'thread': u'Sujet TOPIQUE UNIQUE-FORUM OFFICIEL Rumeurs- News-Infos-Photos-BA-Compte rebours de RAMBO V'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Vos citations prfres du Seigneur des Anneaux'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Piranha 3-D'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Fanarts - vos crations AVATAR'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Sucker Punch'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Sucker Punch'} {u'thread': u'Sujet In brightest day in blackest night Green Lantern le film les news c est ici'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur The Expendables'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Twilight - Chapitre 4 rvlation'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Meeting du TDLCDFDSW pour Juin 2011'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic Unique Harry Potter et les Reliques de la Mort Partie II News Photo Bande annonce '} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Twilight - Chapitre 4 - r\u03b9v\u03b9lation'} {u'thread': u'Topic Unique Harry Potter et les Reliques de la Mort (Partie II) [News, Photo, Bande annonce ----]'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Le Choc des Titans'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Le club des fans de cin'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Le Dernier matre de lair'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Black Swan'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Black Swan'} {u'thread': u"Commentaire sur - Tron l'h\u03b9ritage"} {u'thread': u'Sujet Armada 2008 rassemblement des fans de POTC pour la prise du port de Rouen membres only'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Tron lhritage'} {u'thread': u'Sujet TOPIC OFFICIEL unique TINTIN news photos scoops '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Iron Man 2'} {u'thread': u"Top des films de l'ann\u03b9e 2011"} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Prince of Persia les sables du temps'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Spider-Man (3D)'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - World Invasion - Battle Los Angeles'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Les Griffes de la nuit'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur World Invasion Battle Los Angeles'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Le merchandising - Les produits drivs'} {u'thread': u'TOPIC OFFICIEL [unique] - TINTIN (news, photos, scoops, ---)'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Predators'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Box office Tron '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Tree of Life'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Tree of Life'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Robin des Bois'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Thor'} {u'thread': u'Sujet THOR de Kenneth Brannagh Topic news'} {u'thread': u'Sujet NEW Signalez ici les nouveaux liens Top Ralisateurs et Ralisatrices des internautes rajouter dans le Sticky'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Topic Unique News Breaking Dawn'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Kick-Ass'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Le Monde de Narnia Chapitre 3 - LOdysse du Passeur daurore'} {u'thread': u"Commentaire sur - Le Monde de Narnia - Chapitre 3 - L'Odyss\u03b9e du Passeur d'aurore"} {u'thread': u'Sujet Top Cinma 2011'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Paranormal Activity'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Marc andr Grondin'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Faisons un grand scenario participatif dHP '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Shutter Island'} {u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Shutter Island'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Pourquoi ce film est il autant dtest '} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Twilight - Chapitre 2 tentation'} {u'thread': u'Top Cin\u03b9ma 2011'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Commentaire sur Rien dclarer'} {u'thread': u'Sujet Discussion autour des news et rumeur du New Superman Project '} {u'thread': u'Discussion autour des news et rumeur du New Superman Project !'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> B = [a["abc"] for a in A]
>>> B
['kjkjl', 'hjhjh', '78787']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use list comprehension:

```
B = sum((i.values() for i in A), [])
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your list as

```
>>> A
[{'abc': 'kjkjl'}, {'abc': 'hjhjh'}, {'abc': '78787'}]
```

You can do something like

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[x.values() for x in A]))
['kjkjl', 'hjhjh', '78787']
>>>
```

Comment: Instead of `chain(* ...)`, you should use `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: @lvc: I somehow overlooked in the document for this Class Method. New things come up everyday

Answer (score 1):

```
B = []
for key, value in A.iteritems():
    B.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the dicts in A only have one element, you can do this ...

```
>>> A = [{'abc': 'kjkjl'},{'abc': 'hjhjh'},{'abc': '78787'}]
>>> B = [x.values()[0] for x in A]
>>> B
['kjkjl', 'hjhjh', '78787']
```