# Extracting values of elements in a list of dictionaries with unicode strings

Tags: python, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting values of elements in a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105593/extracting-values-of-elements-in-a-list-of-dictionaries)

A is a python dictionary with unicode strings as follows:

```
A = [{'abc': 'Top Cin\u03b9ma 2011'},{'abc': 'D\u03b9bat autours sur les news ET rumeurs -   D'},{'abc': '78787'}]
```

How can I remove the unicode strings in 'abc' from A and make a new list:

```
B = ['Top Cin\u03b9ma 2011','D\u03b9bat autours sur les news ET rumeurs -   D','78787']
```

The answers in [Extracting values of elements in a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105593/extracting-values-of-elements-in-a-list-of-dictionaries) doesn't work for unicodes.

**EDIT:** I still get the following error using the solutions:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u03b9' in position 10:        character maps to <undefined>
```

The actual data structure is as follows:

```
A =

{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic de la communaut des fans de Star Wars  '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic Unique La Communaut des Fans de Pirates des Caraibes '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Pandora - Topic de la communaut des fans de Avatar et de James Cameron '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Au-del de Brokeback  ple-mle'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  X Men 4  The Wolvy Gang fanfic'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Transformers 3'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  le Photogramme - saison 2'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Une mditation sur lamour de la beaut'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 2'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Inception'}
{u'thread': u'ALED - Cin\u03b9ma'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Twilight - Chapitre 3  hsitation'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet   Topic unique  La Justice league prvu pour 2013'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 1'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Harry Potter et les reliques de la mort - partie 1'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Avatar'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Rebecca and Billy s fan'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  ALED - Bistrot'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  ALED - Jeux'}
{u'thread': u'ALED - Bistrot'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic Unique News Transformers III'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic Unique News  Scream 4 Infos photos BA promo Sans HSFlood '}
{u'thread': u'ALED - Jeux'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  ALED - Musique'}
{u'thread': u'ALED - Musique'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Batmanet une Lgende '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  The Dark Knight Rises'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Resident Evil  Afterlife'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Jake Sully lhomme qui marchait dans sa tte '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  De qui Peter Jackson croit-il se moquer'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Saw 3D'}
{u'thread': u'[Topic Unique] News Spider-Man reboot'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Dbat autours sur les news ET rumeurs D'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Scream 4'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Le Top 100 des internautes'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic des news Bilbo le Hobbit prquelle du Seigneur des Anneaux Spoilers possibles'}
{u'thread': u'D\u03b9bat autours sur les news ET rumeurs -D'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - The Dark Knight Rises'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Top Cinma 2010'}
{u'thread': u'Topic des news Bilbo le Hobbit (pr\u03b9quelle du Seigneur des Anneaux) Spoilers possibles-'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Pirates des Carabes  la Fontaine de Jouvence'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Lunique et vritable explication de matrix revolutions'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic DE SECOURS de la communaut des fans de STAR WARS'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  X-Men Le commencement'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - X-Men Le commencement'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  TOPIQUE UNIQUE-FORUM OFFICIEL Rumeurs- News-Infos-Photos-BA-Compte  rebours de RAMBO V'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Vos citations prfres du Seigneur des Anneaux'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Piranha 3-D'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Fanarts - vos crations AVATAR'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Sucker Punch'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Sucker Punch'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  In brightest day in blackest night Green Lantern le film les news c est ici'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  The Expendables'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Twilight - Chapitre 4  rvlation'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Meeting du TDLCDFDSW pour Juin 2011'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic Unique Harry Potter et les Reliques de la Mort Partie II News Photo Bande annonce '}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Twilight - Chapitre 4 - r\u03b9v\u03b9lation'}
{u'thread': u'Topic Unique Harry Potter et les Reliques de la Mort (Partie II) [News, Photo, Bande annonce ----]'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Le Choc des Titans'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Le club des fans de cin'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Le Dernier matre de lair'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Black Swan'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Black Swan'}
{u'thread': u"Commentaire sur - Tron l'h\u03b9ritage"}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Armada 2008 rassemblement des fans de POTC pour la prise du port de Rouen  membres only'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Tron lhritage'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  TOPIC OFFICIEL unique  TINTIN  news photos scoops '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Iron Man 2'}
{u'thread': u"Top des films de l'ann\u03b9e 2011"}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Prince of Persia  les sables du temps'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Spider-Man (3D)'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - World Invasion - Battle Los Angeles'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Les Griffes de la nuit'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  World Invasion  Battle Los Angeles'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Le merchandising - Les produits drivs'}
{u'thread': u'TOPIC OFFICIEL [unique] - TINTIN  (news, photos, scoops, ---)'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Predators'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Box office Tron '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Tree of Life'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Tree of Life'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Robin des Bois'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Thor'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  THOR de Kenneth Brannagh Topic news'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  NEW Signalez ici les nouveaux liens Top Ralisateurs et Ralisatrices des internautes  rajouter dans le Sticky'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Topic Unique News Breaking Dawn'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Kick-Ass'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Le Monde de Narnia  Chapitre 3 - LOdysse du Passeur daurore'}
{u'thread': u"Commentaire sur - Le Monde de Narnia - Chapitre 3 - L'Odyss\u03b9e du Passeur d'aurore"}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Top Cinma 2011'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Paranormal Activity'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Marc andr Grondin'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Faisons un grand scenario participatif dHP '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Shutter Island'}
{u'thread': u'Commentaire sur - Shutter Island'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Pourquoi ce film est il autant dtest '}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Twilight - Chapitre 2  tentation'}
{u'thread': u'Top Cin\u03b9ma 2011'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Commentaire sur  Rien  dclarer'}
{u'thread': u'Sujet  Discussion autour des news et rumeur du New Superman Project '}
{u'thread': u'Discussion autour des news et rumeur du New Superman Project !'}
```

Comment: How does that linked question not work?

Comment: It is a duplicate, whatever OP says.

Comment: @Marcin that's my question, it doesn't work for the kind of data in the dictionary. as I have added in the edit.

Comment: @Marcin if you see the error in the link I put.

Comment: @codious So, python gives you a link to an SO question as an error?

Comment: @marcin: i didn't want to edit the question once somebody answered so I put a new question with that link here. I hope that's not too bad.

Comment: @codious Editing your question is encouraged, especially here where it is a duplicate of another trivial question.

Comment: @marcin Ok, will follow that, I read in a post it was bad to edit/change a question after someone answered to it. could you remove the downvote?

Comment: @codious Absolutely not. This is still a duplicate of another trivial question, with no evidence that you have tried at all to resolve your own problem.

Comment: @marcin ok, if that's the case.

Comment: Also, I just realised that this is a duplicate of your own question.

Comment: @marcin I tried to explain to you that I changed the question with a new one instead of changing the one that somebody answered. but yes, it created a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's wrong with `values()` for each dictionary in A?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through list A and for each in d in the list, call **values** method that returns a list of values contained in dictionary, then get the first item from that list.

```
>>> [d.values()[0] for d in A]
['Top Cin\\u03b9ma 2011', 'D\\u03b9bat autours sur les news ET rumeurs -   D', '78787']
```

Comment: doesn't work. error as in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the prettiest solution, but I believe this does what you are looking for

```
[i.values()[0] for i in A]
```

I am assuming the '}' in B as shown by you are the result of an editing mistake, otherwise, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y['abc']], A, [])
```

Comment: Try actually running this code.

Comment: @Marcin I misread the original input structure, now it should be ok